How to append List and texts in React Js as a FormData
here i want to pass list on FormData with text items too.
Below i have mention all the backend and frontend code with accepted data.

I am facing error as product_image":["This field is required."] Though i have passed product_image in FormData But the thing is i have appended as a list in formdata but its being string when appended so please help me.

This Data is only Accepted by Django When using Postman, But now as a FormData is needed using React JS.
{
    "Name": "1",
    "category": "1",
    "Description": "1",
    "archive": "true",
    "Banner": {},
    "product_image": [
        {
            "Name": "img[0]",
            "image": {},
            "secret_key": "Keys"
        },
        {
            "Name": "img[1]",
            "image": {},
            "secret_key": "Keys"
        }
    ],
}



p_details = { "Name": "1", "category": 1, "Description": "1", "archive": true, "Banner": {}, }

p_img = { "Name": "img", "Image": { "0": {}, "1": {} } }

Here {} means File
This is Frontend React Js code
    const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();

        const products = new FormData();

        Object.keys(p_details).forEach((key) => products.append(key, p_details[key]));

        // Iterate over the Image object and append each file
        var parentObj = [];

        for (var key in p_imgs.Image) {
            if (p_imgs.Image.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                var file = p_imgs.Image[key];
                var nameWithKey = p_imgs.Name + "[" + key + "]";
                var obj = {
                    "Name": nameWithKey,
                    "user": 2,
                    "image": file,
                    "secret_key": "Keys"
                };
                parentObj.push(obj);
            }
        }
        products.append('product_image', JSON.stringify(parentObj));
       

  try {
            const response = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/product/create/', {
                method: 'POST',
                body: products
            });
            
            if (!response.ok) {
                const errorMessage = await response.text();
                throw new Error(`Server error: ${response.status} - ${errorMessage}`);
            }

            console.log('File uploaded successfully.', response);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error uploading file:', error);
            console.error('Error uploading file:', error.response.data);
        }        
    };

This is Django Serializers.py code
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    product_image = ProductImageSerializer(many = True)

    class Meta:
         model = ProductSize
         fields = "__all__"


The for loop in handleSubmit() has a lot going on in it and because it isn’t self contained, we cannot deduce what is really going on and what each variable represents. Add a [example] to the OP so that it becomes easy to deduce.

Hello Canon i could not get you. I have provided all my code can you please help me i need to add array of multiple objects in the formData.

My code is running in postman but i couldnot add array of multiple objects using formData

Edit the OP to include the declarations of these variables: p_details, p_imgs and any others.

p_details  = {
"Name": "1",
"category": 1,
"Description": "1",
"archive": true,
"Banner": {},
}
p_img = {
"Name": "img",
"Image": {
"0": {},
"1": {}
}
}
here {} means File.
I hope you get it Please help me its been more than a week finding a solution.

Edit the OP with this information.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

There is so much wrong with your implementation. If you want to attach images and I guess that is what you are doing in postman, this is definitely not the way to go about it. If on the other hand you are not attaching images then you don’t even need FormData. Nonetheless you can still use FormData if that is what the Server requires.

I am adding image in Banner and p_img

Can you please help me other ways of using array of multiple objects and uploading image

Sorry for the delay in response. I had an emergency at the office. I can’t add an answer for you because it will end up being very vague. All I’ll say is this; what you are currently doing is not a way to add File to FormData on the browser. To receive File from users, you have to use a form input element, handle input and add the File to FormData(or even construct a FormData from the form element itself). A quick tutorial on this will help you out. This tutorial is something I would highly recommend.
